# Netbeans: Is custom autocomplete possible?

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete

I am using Netbeans 7.2.

Currently I run on to a small 'issue' when working with database objects, so called `Bean`s. Whenever I type the class name on a new line, like: `TableBean` it (suggests to) autocomplete it to `TableBean tableBean;`.

For practically everything this is valid behaviour, however I would like it to suggest `TableBean table;` as I do not want all those beans scattered around.

Would there be anyone being able to help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tools -> Options menu. Then in Editor -> Code Templates tab.

Take a look in the examples there. You can do pretty much things with NetBeans code completion.

Answer (score 1):

After completion to `TableBean tableBean;` press CTRL-BACKSPACE. This will remove the "Bean" from "tableBean"